# A function that returns the High() of an Integer type

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Is there a function in Firebird that returns the High() or Low() of the integer types (Integer, BigInt)?

An example may be...

```
SELECT HIGH(integer) FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

will result in

```
2147483647
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only way to get it is to write a custom UDF.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such function. The values are fixed, so there is little need for such a function. An `INTEGER` always has the max value of 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, a `BIGINT` always has the max value of 2<sup>63</sup> - 1.